# How to provide limited control to non-account owners in Twitter

Tags: twitter, user-accounts

I want to provide an external freelancer access to our corporate Twitter account, without giving that person the option to hijack the account. Sort of like the page managers function in Facebook, where I, as admin, can revoke access to a page manager.
What would be the best way to go about this for Twitter?
Is it possible and if not: are there 3rd party tools which could help?

I could probably setup the account for the freelancer and later change my password, but I'd rather provide that user with a separate login.

**update**

What settings do I need:

Must have: freelancer must NOT be able to delete account / change password / change username / change avatar. Freelancer IS able to: send Direct Messages and Tweets. Follow new users.

Nice to have: freelancer can also unfollow users.

Comment: What do you want the freelancer to be able to do, and not to be able to do?

Answer (score 1):

Using a service like [Hootsuite.com](https://hootsuite.com) would likely be your best bet. You can then have more team members and have control over who can do what as well. Specifically, the descriptions on the [Teams](https://hootsuite.com/features/teams) page describe exactly what you wish to do.

There are other service like Hoot Suite as well if you don't like that exact one.